# Edit Title Tag Wordpress tag.php

Tags: wordpress, tags, page-title

I'am trying to build an Input field for setting a custom HTML title-tag on tag.php in Wordpress. I archived it on page.php with custom fields. But it have no idea how to get it working on tag.php.

In My Function i have now:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'orweb_custom_title');
function orweb_custom_title( $title ) {
if ( ! is_singular() ) return $title;
$custom_title = trim(get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'title', true ));
if( ! empty( $custom_title ) ){
    $custom_title = esc_html( $custom_title );
    $title['title'] = $custom_title;
    }
return $title;
}
function orweb_custom_title_old($title){
if ( ! is_singular() ) return;
$custom_title = trim(get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'title', true));
if( ! empty( $custom_title )  ){
    $custom_title = esc_html( $custom_title );
    $title = $custom_title;
    }
return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'orweb_custom_title_old', 10, 2);
```

Found here: https://orbitingweb.com/blog/custom-seo-friendly-title-tags-wordpress/.